# Is there any DLC for Agarest Generations of War Zero

Tags: record-of-agarest-war-zero

i've been reading though walkthroughs to see what the hell i have done wrong to get to the point where i get slaughtered on the first turn in this consecutive battle i'm in (it's the one where you fight 3 pink troll dudes and one of the Larva who have been changed, quite sure it was the guy in the Red Armour, Azert i think his name was) and i keep reading about these DLC dungeons.

i have the European Version released by Ghostlight, i checked for DLC for Agarest Generations of War Zero maybe a month ago and only saw the Agarest Generations of War 2 there (which is strange cause i previously brought all of Agarest Generations of War DLC prior the upgrade to the Playstation Store)

Is there any DLC for Agarest Generations of War Zero for the European Version or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there apparently is, according to Ghostlight, the DLC is available in UK Playstation Stores but not in Australian Playstation Stores due to the fact the Agarest Generations of War Zero wasn't submitted for an OFLC Rating bellow is the replay i got

"Sadly Agarest_0 wasn't submitted for an OFLC rating. Without the rating we are unable to sell it in Australia. I would like to say at this point this doesn't mean to say that it wont happen. We are always reviewing which games are available in which countries."

EDIT: It seems that the DLC is available in the UK Store and since games brought from the UK should be compatible with their own DLC it should only take creating a UK PSN Account and buying UK PSN Cards

weird thing that gets me is that UK Games can have DLC from the Australian Playstation Store work for them has i've done so with Agarest Generations of War, Atelier Totori, Atelier Meruru, Hyperdimension Neptunia and because of that why wasn't the DLC sumbitted for an OFLC rating cause it's very likely Aussies would buy UK games as the UK is in the PAL Region which no matter what with game, it's going to be 100% compatible if there is region locking, maybe Ghostlight think it'll be refused rating which wouldn't supprise me, the Australian Government is the biggest Troll when it comes to game (look how long we waited for our R Rating and we still have to wait till next year for it to come into effect)